# Code running since infinite time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6, python-2.x, python-2.5

Below is my code. It has been running since infinite time (almost a day). I am unable to figure out if it's because there are many loops or because there is come unending loop. Following is my code :

```
mat1 = np.zeros((1024,1024,360),dtype=np.int32)

k = 498
gamma = 0.00774267
R = 0.37
g = np.zeros(1024)
g[0:512] = np.linspace(0,1,512)
g[513:] = np.linspace(1,0,511)
pf = np.zeros((1024,1024,360))
pf1 = np.zeros((1024,1024,360))

for b in range(0,1023) :
  for beta in range(0,359) :
    for a in range(0,1023) :
      pf[a,b,beta] = (R/(((R**2)+(a**2)+(b**2))**0.5))*mat[a,b,beta]
    pf1[:,b,beta] = np.convolve(pf[:,b,beta],g,'same')

for x in range(0,1023) :
  for y in range(0,1023) :
    for z in range(0,359) :
        for beta in range(0,359) :
          a = R*((-x*0.005)*(sin(beta)) + (y*0.005)*(cos(beta)))/(R+(x*0.005)*(cos(beta))+(y*0.005)*(sin(beta)))
          b = z*R/(R+(x*0.005)*(cos(beta))+(y*0.005)*(sin(beta)))
          U = R+(x*0.005)*(cos(beta))+(y*0.005)*(sin(beta))
          l = math.trunc(a)
          m = math.trunc(b)
          if (0<=l<1024 and 0<=m<1024) : 
              mat1[x,y,z] = mat[x,y,z] + (R**2/U**2)**pf1[l,m,beta]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.transform import iradon
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from PIL import Image
I8 = (((mat1 - mat1.min()) / (mat1.max() - mat1.min())) *   255.9).astype(np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(I8)
img.save("M4.png")
im = Image.open("M4.png")
im.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to the halting problem. Perhaps you could add some logging and determine where the program is spending its time.

Comment: What happens if you add logging (printing the iterators) inside the loops to track ongoing progress? That would be my first step.

Comment: Almost a day isn't infinite.

Comment: I tried printing 'pf' and it keeps giving the values with every iteration. But that itself was very slow. So I guess the next loop would take even more time.

Comment: It has been running for a day and is still running without any errors or results and I have no idea when it will stop running. And so infinite.

Comment: .... like, before the big bang?

Comment: I'd advise you to log a timestamp within the x-loop. This will show you how long this loop takes. Once you know this, you can multiply this with the number of times the x-loop is needed, and you'll know when to expect a final result. For your information, this is done as follows:
`from datetime import datetime`
`print(datetime.now())`

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta That's also not *infinite*. It's *only* about **13.82 billion years** (**infinite** is *really*, *really*, *really* big).

Comment: Yup, hence "*before* the big bang".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your code will run in finite time.**

However, if you sprinkle in a few print statements to see where you are in the various loops, you can see why it will take so long.  For instance, after the `for y in range(0, 1023):` line, add a `print(y)` line, you'll see it takes about 1 second between each printout, so that part of your code will take about 1023 x 1023 seconds, which is 12 days.  You may want to look into modules like `multiprocessing` to parallelize some of the calculations, but even on a 32 core machine your code will still take around half a day to run.

There are several small optimizations you can do, I'm not sure entirely how much they will help.  For one, you can calculate `sin(beta)` and `cos(beta)` once each in the inner loop, rather than 4 times each.  You can calculate `R**2` once globally, rather than every time inside the inner loop.  You can calculate `x*0.005` and `y*0.005` less often, as well as `a` and `l`.  You can split up the conditional involving `l` and `m`, and move the `l` conditional up above the `z` loop, thereby potentially avoiding that `z` loop sometimes.

Also, it seems weird that you're having `beta` range from 0 to 359, and then calculating its `sin` and `cos` values.  Those functions expect arguments in radians, e.g. the sine of a right angle is not `sin(90)` but rather `sin(math.pi/2)`.